# Problems with INSERT INTO syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, insert-into

I am trying to insert data from one table into another. However, I need it to insert where two other values of the table are equal. I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO table_one(admin_id)
SELECT id FROM admin
WHERE table_one.employee_code = admin.employee_code
```

I get an error like:

```
Unknown column 'admin.employee_code' in 'where clause'
```

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

If this question has been asked somewhere else ( I'm sure it has, but I wasn't sure what to ask and couldn't find it ) please link me to it.

Thank you

EDIT

Turns out it was a case where I should have updated.

Here is the MySQL syntax that worked.

```
UPDATE table_one as t1 JOIN
   admin as a
   ON t1.employee_code = a.employee_code
SET admin_id = a.id;
```

Comment: do you want to update or insert? how can you insert a new row for an already existing id ?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to *update* the table, not insert a new record:

```
UPDATE table_one t1 JOIN
       admin a
       ON t1.employee_code = a.employee_code
    SET admin_id = admin.id;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer. I feel silly now but we all start somewhere :)